# Rails button id and click button events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am working on rails app ,  this is the code i am using :

```
<%= button_to "New", :action => "update", remote: true%>
```

Now I want button id so that I can initiate JavaScript event when it is clicked , simple html button which was initially used is :

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Save" action="update" alignment="center" />
```

Any guesses?

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) shows, there's no way to do this directly.  The best way I've found is to add an id to the parent class - `span` works well.

```
<span id="btn">
  <%= button_to "New", :action => "update", remote: true%>
</span>
```